# Is it possible to get a list of relevant words from a full-text index given a specific row?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I wuld like to do som automatic tagging of incoming text in our system and I was wondering if a full-text index is capable of providing a a ranked list of words given an indexed row.

If not, do you have any suggestions on how to do this? We already have a system in place for auto tagging but its fairly brute-force (aka. slow) in its method and it is not always  yielding a good list of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think so. From [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

The scenarios given for using `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` are

- “I want to know how many keywords the full-text index contains”
- “I want to know if a keyword is part of a given doc/row”
- “I want to know how many times a keyword appears in the whole full-text index”  (sum(occurrence_Count) where keyword=……)
- “I want to know how many times a keyword appears in a given doc/row”
- “I want to know how many keywords a given doc/row contains”
- “I want to retrieve all the keywords belonging to a given doc/row”

Comment: Thanks I think from what you're telling me that the scenario I need it for is covered.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I were looking for. Some other projects has occupied me but I think now I'll try to work out a solution using full text index. Now the next problem will be to create a full-text index on a multi-language column. Do you know if I should simply split it up into more columns or tables?